# How to apply the value from .map() to another collection in Firebase

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 collections in Firestore. One's called images and the other accounts. Every image has a user ID. Based on that user ID I want to load their display name, which is in accounts. Every document in accounts has a userid and a displayName.

```
{docs && docs.map(doc => (
  <Grid className="img-item" item key={doc.id} xs={12} md={6} lg={4}>
    <img src={doc.url} alt="uploaded pic" />
    <Typography variant="subtitle1"> By {doc.userID} </Typography>
  </Grid>
```

I want to load in userName based on that userID. How would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your purpose. you should map on users and inside the map, you should filter the images that have userID of the current user.

```
       accounts.map((user) => (
        <Grid className="img-item" item key={user.userID} xs={12} md={6} lg={4}>
          {images
            .filter((image) => image.userID === user.userID)
            .map((image) => (
              <img
                src={image.url}
                key={`image-${user.userID}`}
                alt="uploaded pic"
              />
            ))}
          <Typography variant="subtitle1"> By {user.userName} </Typography>
        </Grid>
      ))
```

I've made an example [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-sunset-2fvj3)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried it and got a "Cannot read property of 'map' of undefined" error. 
`> 11 | return <Grid container justify="center">
     | ^  12 |     {docs2.map((user) => (
  13 |         <Grid className="img-item" item key={user.userID} xs={12} md={6} lg={4}>
  14 |             {docs`

Comment: that means docs2 is undefined, be sure the docs2 array has value

Comment: Would there be a better way for me to show you my code? I know I'm messing up somewhere with docs2 (importing the accounts), but I dont see exactly where.

Comment: put them on https://codesandbox.io/ or fork my project https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-sunset-2fvj3